# Views: show only one node per select box value

Tags: views

I created a Block showing the latest 3 articles ("pets") as teaser (not using fields). The content type has a field `type` which can be **dog**, **cat** or **other**.

Now i want to show only one of each `type`: one dog, one cat and one other. I don't have any idea how i can do that... I have some filter criteria (content-type=pet, available=yes, public=yes) and sort criteria (content:date_arrived desc) and limited to 3 items.

Thanks for any help / hint!

I'm using drupal 7 and the newest views-module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing it's difficult to make just with the views UI (the aggregation will not work)
If you don't want the solution of Anil Sagar, i have another solution with some theming.

- Go to `format => setting` : In **Grouping field Nr.1** select your field `type` (left)
- Now your result will by group by type (dog, cat and others) You can see an extrat of the output. (right)

[image]

- Go to `Advanced setting => Other => Theme information`

[image: views settings 3]

- Copy / Paste `views-view-list.tpl.php` in your new template and make some modification

  ```
   <?php print $wrapper_prefix; ?>
   <?php if (!empty($title)) : ?>
     <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php print $list_type_prefix; ?>
   //Add this
   <?php $x = 0; ?>
   <?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
      <?php if($x < 1): ?>    
      <li class="<?php print $classes_array[$id]; ?>"><?php print $row; ?></li>
      <?php $x++; ?>
    <?php endif ?>  
  <?php endforeach; ?> 
  <?php print $list_type_suffix; ?>
  <?php print $wrapper_suffix; ?>
  ```

And you'll have what you wanted:

[image: views settings 4]

Comment: Great, that worked! Thanks a lot! I just had to force using fields because i set it to display unformatted list of teasers and remove title output in template.

Answer (score 0):

I think below solution should work.

- Create three block views.
- Each will have three different type filters -- 1st view block (Type: dog) -- 2nd view block (Type: cat), 3rd view bloc (Type: Other)
- Restrict number of nodes to 1 in pager settings.

Enable all three blocks one below other or use views attachment feature as explained [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6961/what-is-the-difference-between-an-attachment-display-and-a-global-view-area).

One more solution for this is using Aggregation feature in views. I haven't tried this but should work i think. Give it a try !

Comment: that would work, but with that methods i will have to edit my hole theme or use dirty tricks. i hope there's a simpler method...

Comment: I tried aggregation as i thought it would be the right place to start, but didn't figure out how to use it to get what i want