# Print a view within another view

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

Here is my situation,

1. I have a view-1 which will list the node titles based on Content: Taxonomy term CONTEXTUAL FILTERS
2. View-2 which will list all the taxonomy terms (of a vocabulary) with node count.

Now how do I print the view-1 as a custom field within view-2.

The reason I am trying to do this is, I am trying to construct a UI which will display the nodes on click on taxonomy terms with count.

I tried using below code to print view-1 as a custom PHP field on view-2, but it did not work for me.

```
    print views_embed_view('view-1','block_1', $row->tid);
```

$row->tid is the term ID argument I am trying to pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using the below code in 'Global: PHP' > 'Output code' field.

```
    <?php print views_embed_view('view-1','default', $row->tid); ?>
```

Comment: Mind that you need the Views PHP (https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module to enable the field *Global: PHP*.

Answer (score 2):

The module [Views Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) may work for you. It's worth to try.

> This module allows you to embed a view as a field in a view. A new
>   field handler is made available, so this can also be used in area
>   (header/footer/empty) handlers as well as rows.
>
> This view handler can accept arguments from fields of the parent view
>   using tokens and pass them into the child view for each row. Raw or
>   rendered token values can be used, as well as static values.

OR

You can even create two displays in a view - one is **Page** and the other is **Attachment**.
For your case, view-2 would be **Page** and view-1 would be **Attachment**.

You can select various settings in the attachment view such as Attach to, Contextual filter, etc.

[image]
[image]

Check [this answer about an attachment view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/7007/2792). I had a book [Drupal 6 Attachment Views](http://www.packtpub.com/drupal-6-attachment-views/book), but could not find a book for D7.